# salvar tempo de questionário

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Fiz um questionário com php e javascript, está tudo certo. Só tem um pequeno detalhe que não estou sabendo qual a melhor maneira de se fazer.

O questionário tem um tempo para ser respondido, e gostaria que caso o usuário que está respondendo sair da pagina ou atualizar, o tempo comece a contar de onde ele parou. Pensei em fazer uma requisição ajax gravando no bd a cada 2s o tempo corrido, mas gostaria de evitar algo que fizesse tantas requisições ao banco de dados em tão pouco tempo assim, ainda mais que o sistema está na amazon, quero evitar para não gerar custos adicionais.

Pensei em outras maneira, como por exemplo, sessions e cookies mas qualquer uma das duas não é eficiente para isso.

Se puderem me ajudar fico muito agradecido, só preciso de uma dica de qual seria na experiência de vocês uma opção mais viável.

Comment: É possível confirmar a saída da página, ai nessa confirmação você salva...

Comment: Sim, mas não são todos os navegadores que onbeforeunload funcionam muito bem. Mas obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o `localStorage`, ela fornece acesso ao armazenamento local para um domínio específico, permitindo que você, por exemplo, adicione, modifique ou exclua itens de dados armazenados.

Salvando no `localStorage` o tempo e uma identificação para o usuário:

```
storage.setItem(usuario, tempo);
```

Lendo o valor:

```
var tempo = storage.getItem(usuario);
```

Você pode usar isso pois os dados armazenados no `localStorage` não expiram.

Mais informações: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Storage

Comment: eu pensei mesmo em usar localStorage Mas o usuário não pode simplesmente apagar isso limpando dados de navegação? Como se faz com cookies, cache etc..? Isso seria um problema tendo em vista que usuário poderia burlar o tempo desse jeito.

Comment: O problema é que o usuário pode apagar esse registro facilmente e responder o questionário com todo o tempo do mundo

Comment: Eu sugiro que você realize com o onunload e onbeforeunload e teste em todos os navegadores possíveis. Aqueles que você não achar o evento correspondente, desabilite a resolução do questionário.

Comment: @MarcusDacorréggio andei pesquisando sobre os eventos onbeforeunload e onunload e vi muitos relatos de que ao usar esses eventos para disparar por exemplo requisições ajax pode ser um problema já que os navegadores pausam tudo ao tentar fechar uma aba, sem falar nos crashs e elas acabam não sendo enviadas. Por esses motivos optei por tentar outras alternaivas, mas pelo que estou vendo vai ser minha única saída por enquanto kkkk. Muito obrigado

Comment: Você pode gravar no banco em intervalos maiores para diminuir a carga, e ainda usar o `localStorage`, se não tiver uma informação local aí você busca do banco, a do local seria uma informação mais precisa do tempo, a do banco seria uma segurança contra quem tentar limpar os dados para burlar esse tempo.